# If/else statement syntax using R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, syntax

I have a semantic question regarding the proper syntax for a *simple* if statement I'm trying to write with R (having a background in coding with Python). What would be the R equivalent to the Python statement:

```
def zsco(data, mean, sd):
    if sd==0:
        z=0
    else:
        z=abs((data-mean)/sd)
    return z
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar way to write in `R` would be

```
zscoR <- function(data, mean, sd) {
     if(sd == 0) {
           0
       } else {
       abs((data - mean)/sd)
     }
    }
```

If all the input parameters have the same length and is greater than 1, then use `ifelse`

```
zscoRM <- function(data, mean, sd) {
   ifelse(sd == 0, 0, abs((data - mean)/sd))
    }
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but I end up getting a warning message saying: "In if (sd==0) {: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" I'll add that this little timbit of code is from a larger script that I've been writing for school

Comment: @EmilyLauren What are the lengths of `sd`, `mean`.  I assume these are of length 1.  `zscoR(1:20, 5, 1.5)`

Comment: More background :P I'm trying to calculate Z scores for a large number of biological experiments and control experiments. An example of when I call my zsco function: I try to iterate the calculation down an entire column (my data frame has 427 rows, each representing a different experiment) to produce a new column of corresponding Z scores. Thus far, the function does just that, but in cases where the standard deviation=0, my new Z score column is filled with "NaN". This is why I want to automatically state is sd==0, z=0. I'm very new at coding with R, but I hope that gives more context!

Comment: @EmilyLauren  I can't reproduce the issue you meantioned `zscoR(1:20, 5, 0)#
[1] 0`

Comment: I think it's because I'm trying to perform the calculation on an entire column where each row of the column has a different value for data, mean and sd

Comment: @EmilyLauren  I guess you are passing `data`, `mean` and `sd` as having the same length.  In that case, use `ifelse` i.e. `ifelse(sd == 0, 0, abs((data - mean)/sd))`